# Laravel simple private conversation structure

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to create a simple private conversation between two users. I've tried following some examples but all i can find is for multiple users in multiple conversations and more complex versions. My endgoal is for simply be able to do `$user->conversations->messages` to get all my conversations and their messages that has been sent between two users.

I only need some help with the structure and relation between the tables to easily find correct conversation for each user and the messages connected to the conversation.

I currently have 3 models for this.

```
User Model
Conversation Model
PrivateMessages Model
```

My tables currently look like this but i think i need to do some changes to them also.

```
users:
id
name

conversations:
id

private_messages:
id
sent_by
sent_to
body
read_at
conversation_id
```

Comment: Your question is too vague.

Comment: Your question is too broad. You have to research about Pusher and Laravel Echo.

Comment: @user2094178 I think you misunderstand, i know what to do with pusher and all after that. My question is more about the structure and relation of model and tables to easily set up a good basic structure to work on.

Comment: @Vincent Let me update my question and i will narrow it down.